# var_dump array(0) { } php

Tags: php, arrays, var-dump

Trying to see if there is actual data in this array:
Here is the query that i am running:

```
 global $wpdb;
    $gather_answers = "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."comments WHERE comment_post_ID = '" . $comment_parent_id . "' ORDER BY comment_date";
    $user_answers = $wpdb->get_results($gather_answers);

    var_dump($user_answers);
```

When i do the var_dump of the array the output is:

```
array(0) { }
```

I have tried to access parts of it like:

```
var_dump($user_answers[0]);
```

But nothing comes up.

Any idea to see if there is any data in this array or not?

Comment: `array(0)` means array has 0 index (empty)

Comment: Trying to learn, why mark down someone for learning...

Comment: To check if there is data in the array use [`count`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var_dump($user_answers);
```

returns nothing?
There is **no data** in the array.

Arrays and objects are explored recursively by [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), so if any data at all was present, it would show up.

Answer (score 1):

Your query likely does not return anything, i.e there are probably not any comments for the post your requesting. If you are positive there are comments, the query might possibly fail because you are treating `comment_post_id` as a string in your query, rather than an integer. Try reformatting it as follows:

```
$gather_answers = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_post_ID = %d ORDER BY comment_date", $comment_parent_id );
```